# How to construct a zero-parameter constructor which sets ageInWeeks and generationNumber to zero, and sets:

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, bluej

1. genus to DEFAULT GENUS
2. species to DEFAULT SPECIES
3. isFemale to true
4. isAlive to true
5. healthCoefficient to DEFAULT HEALTH COEFFICIENT
6. identificationNumber to the newly incremented value of      numberOfGuppiesBorn

Long story short, aim struggling over a problem where i need to build a constructor.

I have read examples off internet but still struggling to understand.

What I have is

```
    public class Guppy
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int YOUNG_FISH = 10;
    int MATURE_FISH = 30;
    int MAXIMUM_AGE_IN_WEEKS = 50;
    double MINIMUM_WATER_VOLUME_ML = 0.25;
    String DEFAULT_GENUS = "Poecilia";
    String DEFAULT_SPECIES = "reticulata";
    double DEFAULT_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT = 0.5;
    double MINIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT = 0.0;
    double MAXIMUM_HEALTH_COEFFICIENT = 1.0;
}

// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private String genus;
private String species;
private int ageInWeeks;
private boolean isFemale;
private int generationNumber;
private boolean isAlive;
private double healthCoefficient;
private int identificationNumber;


/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Guppy
 */
public Guppy()
{   












}
```

Comment: public Guppy() is your zero-parameter constructor. Inside it, you set each variable value as requested.

Comment: Leo, do you mind giving me an example how do i start with the first line inside the constructor with a particular first variable? this would help a lot

Comment: sure. add to your constructor something like "genus = DEFAULT_GENUS;"

Comment: thank you! it seems simple, ill keep working on it. Other question to you: I have already searched for the difference between static and final. I am totally not sure which variables should be set to static and which ones to final because I don't know which once of them we are going to change and which ones should stay final. Please ask me questions if I am not clear, english is not my first language.

Comment: On your second comment, I suggest you read the standard Java tutorial starting at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind taking a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37537507/building-two-java-constructors-for-my-project-guppy-what-should-i-do-to-impro